# Which human has the highest specified IQ in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel

I initially assumed Tony Stark had the highest IQ, but then I remembered Reed Richards - "Smartest Man Alive apparently". Then I read somewhere its Reed's son Franklin.

Anyways people on Stack Exchange obviously have more knowledge about this so, - So who has the highest specified IQ in the Marvel Universe??"

To perhaps make this question answerable, let's limit the character to human only)

Kindly specify the IQ if possible and will prefer canon answers.

Comment: _You know, I'm something of a scientist myself._

Comment: This might be broad I think, considering many people have been considered to be the smartest depending on the universe/work. Sometimes it's Tony Stark. Sometimes his father is considered to be smarter than him. Sometimes, Bruce Banner is considered to be smarter than Tony. And let's not forget Dr. Doom.

Comment: I have limited it down to humans if that helps, but if someone has a non human answer, I'll change the question and accept it

Comment: Franklin Richards is a whole can of worms.

Comment: Marvel currently has Moon Girl listed as the smartest superhero in the Marvel Universe. https://www.marvel.com/articles/comics/10-smartest-super-heroes   Can anyone find her IQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Reed Richards](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Reed_Richards_(Earth-1610)) of [Earth-1610](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-1610) -- also known as the Ultimate Universe -- was listed with an IQ of **267** at age 16.

> [image: Ultimate Fantastic Four #20, page 8]
>
> <sub>*[Ultimate Fantastic Four #20](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_20)* (August, 2005)</sub>

Comment: Who is that displaying envy/disparaging Reed? Do we know their IQ?

Comment: @Spencer - The character speaking there is [Rhona Burchill](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rhona_Burchill_(Earth-1610)). Not sure if her IQ was ever specified, but I'll look into it a bit later. For what it's worth though, she was turned down at least partly due to her poor psych profile, not just a lack of raw intellect.

Comment: I'd remove the word "just" from that last sentence until the evidence is in.

Comment: If there was "1" instead of two in his "score" then it might mean something, but with this author just shown lack of understanding of the topic.

Comment: @Mithoron Nobody's looking for scientific accuracy in a work of this sort.

Comment: @Spencer - I think my statement is valid as-is. It only asserts that a lack of intellect was certainly not the only reason Rhona was passed over in favour of Reed. It doesn't assert that a lack of intellect necessarily had anything to do with it. I took a look at all four of her appearances, as listed at the Marvel Database, and didn't see her IQ specified anywhere.

Comment: @Mithoron Supposedly the highest recorded IQ is 263, so in a fictional world someone having 267 isnt unreasonable.

Comment: "Guinness retired the "Highest IQ" category in 1990 after concluding IQ tests were too unreliable to designate a single record holder." So "highest IQ" in real life is not really a real thing we can discuss. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_vos_Savant was said to be 186-228. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Ung-yong was said to be 210. I also see lots of others with estimates 200+, but almost none with *measurements* 200+.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Just because Guinness doesn't have an award for it doesn't mean that "highest IQ" is a nonexistent metric.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Guinness **removed** their award for it **because** its a nonexistent metric. There is a person with a highest IQ, but we don't have an accurate way to measure it, so we have no real idea who that person is or was. (This was in response to knighwatch, who said the highest was 263, presumably referring to Ainan Cawley. Cawley's IQ is disputed, and he is not listed on most "highest IQ" lists)

Comment: If one has a car that can go 100 mph, and another car that can go 200 mph, then the relationship between those two cars is obvious.  It's (for lack of a better word) _linear_.  But it seems reasonable to suppose that IQ scores aren't that way; that  an IQ of 300 would be _fundamentally different_ from an IQ of 100.  An IQ test written by mere mortals couldn't possibly be an accurate gauge.

Comment: @MooingDuck: "There is a person with a highest IQ" <-- Well at this point we're largely splitting hairs. Even if we stipulate the real-world measure accuracy problem, it's easy to believe that the fictional world can either measure it more precisely or simply _thinks_ they can.

Comment: At that level the test becomes meaningless as you're smarter than the person who devised the test.